# Predefined subpatterns vs compiled regex

Tags: regex, perl

Why would you use a predefined subpattern when a compiled regex can do the same. Seems like the compiled regex is better since you can also capture the output.Here is an example:

```
my $open_tag  = qr {<head>};
my $any       = qr {.*?};
my $close_tag = qr {</head>};

if (/($open_tag) ($any) ($close_tag)/x){
  print $1;
  print $2;
  print $3;
}
```

Versus:

```
if (m {
           (? (DEFINE)
               (? <OPEN_TAG>  <head>  )
               (? <ANY>       .*?     )
               (? <CLOSE_TAG> </head> )
            )
           (?&OPEN_TAG) (?&ANY) (?&CLOSE_TAG)
         }x
)

### Won't work below
print $1; print $2; print $3;
}
```

#

Keep in mind im pretty new to Perl.
Thanks in advance.
-Tim

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons for using qr//:

1. What you propose as an alternative relies on new features.
2. The patterns passed to qr// aren't necessarily hardcoded or constant.

Comment: Is it possible to capture in the above example the value for (?&OPEN_TAG)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, and it doesn't seem to be related to either the question or the answer.